# Minimum flow in a flow network

Tags: algorithms, correctness-proof, network-flow

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a flow network with a source $s$ and sink $t$.

However, the constraints are a bit different:

Conservation constraint is as usual.

For each edge $e \in E$, we have that the flow $f$ maintains that $f(e) \geq c(e)$ when $c(e)$ is the capacity of $e$.

The question asks to write an algorithm that finds the minimum flow in $G$. Here is what I wrote:

1. Create an array $A$ of size $|E|$.
2. Run a loop $|E|$ times or until you don't have a path from $s$ to $t$ and do:

   a. Run BFS scan from $s$.

   b. Find a path $P$ from $s$ to $t$ using step (a).

   c. Insert the scan data from step (b) into the cell corresponding to the scan number in
   array $A$ – the value of the edge with the maximum capacity in the path $P$ (we will mark this edge as $e$), the edge $e$, the path $P$.

   d. Remove $e$ from $G$.
3. Find the minimum in $A$ with respect to the edge value.
4. The minimum flow will be the value of the edge in step 3, and the flow itself will be on the path corresponding to the path of the edge in step 3 in the cell of $A$.

Time complexity:

$$(\underbrace{O(|E|)}_{\text{step 1}} + \underbrace{\left( \sum_{i=1}^{|E|} O(i+|V|) \right)}_{\text{step 2}} + \underbrace{O(|E|)}_{\text{step 3}} = O(|E|^2 + |E| \cdot |V|) = \underbrace{O(|V|^4)}_{\text{worst case}})$$

This result is better than the Edmonds–Karp algorithm.

I don't know how to prove if this solution is correct.

I tried to prove it by contradiction, but I didn't go far.

Here I will demonstrate the result of the algorithm on the following flow network:
[image: An example for G]

Comment: Can you tell us the context in which you encountered this problem statement?  What is the motivation, or the source where you saw it?  "I don't know how to start" questions often aren't an ideal fit here.  We're looking for questions that will be useful to others.  For your purposes, a good starting point might be to implement your algorithm, implement one that is known to be correct, generate many random test cases, and see if your algorithm always gives the correct results.

Comment: Simply try with a graph that has multiple paths from the source to sink; you will get your counter-example.

Comment: @D.W. This is a question from a test in an "Algorithms" course I am studying.
Where I study, there are no lectures, no professors to explain things to you, and unfortunately, no one answers the emails and is not available during reception hours.
There is no solution attached to this question, and really this is the only place I can ask if what I wrote is correct.
I understand and respect the rules you mentioned.
I added a picture to better illustrate my point.
I really couldn't make progress in the proof/refutation of the algorithm, and that's why things were worded like that.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami I tried to work with multiple graphs. I added on of them in the post. Maybe I don't fully understand the definition of  the minimum flow in the question, but I think that the example in the picture is correct.

Comment: What you show on the figure in not a valid flow. For example the flow on edge $(s,v)$ is $0$ but the "capacity" of $(s,v)$ is $7$.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the pictures. Please note that in your solution the constraint $f(e) > c(e)$ does not holds for every edge, for example: edge $(s,v)$ has flow $0$ but $c(e) = 7$.

Comment: @Steven Thank you !!

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Thank you !!